# ListView side index doesn't fit screen

Tags: android, listview

In Android development, I have a `LinearLayout` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_inprogress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Congress API"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/side_index"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#c3c3c3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And index item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/side_list_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

I have a side index on the right side. It's A to Z. However the actual UI only shows A to V because no enough space. Padding of each item is 3. How can I make the side index to fit the screen?

If I change the padding to 1dp in index item text view, it will become too small. All I want is automatically fit the screen side. How can I make it happen?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

how about making the linearlayout able to scroll vertically ? If the answer is affirmative, then go ahead and add a scrollview outside the linearlayout ~